# Convert Epoch to Datetime in AWS Glue / pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I have a dataframe that I'm processing in AWS Glue using pyspark and one of the messages in my df looks like this:

```
{  
   "version":"0.0.1",
   "device_id":"df4c13ddddb1bb8fea9fe762",
   "session_id":"721cf47cf8408b30bc57743717",
   "session_start":1508450739332,
   "source_id":"5",
   "body":{  
      "message_id":"2e6d83c677a7b4f3683366d",
      "message_type":1,
      "message_time":1508450739332,
      "url":"http://sample_url/"
   },
   "partition_0":"2017",
   "partition_1":"10",
   "partition_2":"19",
   "partition_3":"22"
}
```

I'm trying to convert body.message_time (epoch in miliseconds) to date time field. I tried from_unixtime function:

```
unnested_df.withColumn("messages_datetime", from_unixtime(unnested_df.body.message_time.divide(1000)).show()
```

Giving me this error:

```
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

I'm simply passing that column into from_unixtime function. Any idea how this can be fixed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an exception because `Column` has no `divide` method. Use `/` operator:

```
unnested_df.withColumn("messages_datetime", from_unixtime(unnested_df.body.message_time / 1000)
```